# Why do my icons cut off on hover, when there isn't a specified height?

Tags: html, css

On [roseannebarr.tumblr.com](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com), when you hover on my icons instead of them going up naturally they are cut off even thought I don't have a set height. I know my HTML is screwed up because I'm using a million ids but my page works off of browser bugs so just ignore it. Any ideas?

This was probablly the dumbest question ever sorry.

Comment: What browser is cutting them off? They're not getting cut off for me in IE, Firefox, or Chrome.

Comment: Same here, none of the images are tall enough.

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, that's one disturbing web site...

Comment: Sorry guys I am just stupid :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not cut off, you make the container smaller by moving the image outside the container using a negative top margin.

A simple solution is to put the black background on the `#block` style intead of on the `#outer` style. That way the image gets the background instead of the container, so the background follows the image when it moves instead of shrinking with the container.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the black background getting cut off when you hover over it? Do you want the whole icon including the background to go up? If so, you should just put the :hover on #outer instead of #block:

```
#outer:hover {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Don't know if that's what you mean. If not, let me know. :)